# How to grep from a file and save the results as separate files

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

I'm trying to grep several patterns, which I have stored in a text file. 
I want to grep each of these patterns in another file and save the results of each grep in a separate text file.

Simplified example:

Data (stored in `targets.txt`):

```
ERR751956   1.1
ERR718556   1.1
ERR775770   1.1
ERR553258   1.1.1
SRR5067466  1.1.1
ERR768007   1.1.1
ERR2515049  1.2.1
ERR2517293  1.2.1
ERR400534   1.2.1
ERR1034610  1.2.2
ERR221606   1.2.2
SRR2101271  1.2.2
ERR718276   2.1
SRR5709934  2.1
SRR5065676  2.2
SRR5709903  2.2
```

I'm trying to group the data based on the first decimal place, so I search for these patterns, which I have stored in a file called `patterns.txt`:

```
"\s1.1
\s1.2
\s2.1
\s2.2"
```

When I run grep individually, it works, e.g.  `grep "\s1.1" targets.txt`

What I want to do though is grep all of these patterns and store the results as a separate file, ideally with the form target_1.1.txt.

I have tried many variations on loops, including this one:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line 
do
    grep "$line" targets.txt > target_"$line".txt
done < patterns.txt
```

However,

1. it saves the file name including the grep command "`\s`", which I don't want, but
2. it doesn't pick up all greps and save them in a file - some of the results are just an empty file.

Again, I have run the ones it doesn't pick up individually, and they print to the screen just fine.

Comment: Are the quotes on the first and last line really in your `patterns.txt` file? I assume they's just accidentally in the question, but if they're actually in the file you should remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Too many processes. Try a `sed`. c.f. the [`sed` reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands) for use of `w`, but basically it outputs the (possibly pre-edited with `s///`) line to a named file.

Note it will truncate any existing file, but as you can see, subsequent writes to the same file append.

So for your given data -

```
$: sed -En '
    /\s1\.1/w target_1.1.txt
    /\s1\.2/w target_1.2.txt
    /\s2\.1/w target_2.1.txt
    /\s2\.2/w target_2.2.txt
' targets.txt

$: # now let's look at the files -
   # grep prepends the filename & a colon

$: grep . target*
target_1.1.txt:ERR751956  1.1
target_1.1.txt:ERR718556   1.1
target_1.1.txt:ERR775770   1.1
target_1.1.txt:ERR553258   1.1.1
target_1.1.txt:SRR5067466  1.1.1
target_1.1.txt:ERR768007   1.1.1
target_1.2.txt:ERR2515049  1.2.1
target_1.2.txt:ERR2517293  1.2.1
target_1.2.txt:ERR400534   1.2.1
target_1.2.txt:ERR1034610  1.2.2
target_1.2.txt:ERR221606   1.2.2
target_1.2.txt:SRR2101271  1.2.2
target_2.1.txt:ERR718276   2.1
target_2.1.txt:SRR5709934  2.1
target_2.2.txt:SRR5065676  2.2
target_2.2.txt:SRR5709903  2.2
```

Here's a simplified example to compare:

```
$: cat in
dog
cat
mouse
flying fox
hairless cat
dingo
panda

$: # allocate lines to files

$: sed '
> /a/w a
> /e/w e
> /i/w i
> /o/w o
> /u/w u
> ' in

$: # now let's look at the files -
   # grep prepends the filename & a colon

$: grep . a e i o u
a:cat
a:hairless cat
a:panda
e:mouse
e:hairless cat
i:flying fox
i:hairless cat
i:dingo
o:dog
o:mouse
o:flying fox
o:dingo
u:mouse
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I found your simpler example confusing when I first looked at it - until I understood it, it seemed like a lot of confusing stuff. Since your solution is very concise in the end, I would suggest starting with a short paragraph explaining what `w` does (maybe just quoting the `sed` manual you linked to), then have your simple example, and finally the solution for OP. Or, even, drop the simplified example and go straight to OP's solution with the `w` explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I like @PaulHodges's solution using `sed`, but here is an alternative solution, closer to your own original script, in case you prefer staying with this type of solution.

The result is very specific to the patterns used, but I find it useful to master variable substitutions in bash, so I think this is worth presenting, even though I prefer Paul's solution.

**Use variable substitutions**

In bash, there are a lot of way to modify variables using variable substitutions. You can use `${var#prefix}` to remove a prefix from `$var`. In your case, `${line#\\s}` will contain just the version number.

So the script can become:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line ; do
   out="target_${line#\\s}"
   grep "$line" targets.txt > "$out"
done < patterns.txt
```

**Escaping the dot**

Now, there is a potential issue: you don't escape `.`, so `1.1` is asking to match `1` followed by anything followed by `1`. You probably want to use `\s1\.1` instead, in which case the script is going to break again. You can fix it by using `${var//pattern/replacement}` which substitutes every occurrence of the pattern:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line ; do
   out="target_${line#\\s}"
   out="${out//\\/}"
   grep "$line" targets.txt > "$out"
done < patterns.txt
```

**More information**

Type `man bash` and search for `##` to learn about all the other variable substitutions it supports (`#`, `%`, `/`, `^`, `,` and their doubled variants are all interesting).

**Missing output: cannot reproduce**

I was not able to reproduce the problem with some output files being empty, so I cannot address it here. If the quotes are literally in your `patterns.txt` file, that could be the problem, otherwise I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it the following way:

```
$ awk '{match($2,/[0-9]+[.][0-9]+/)}
       {print > ("target_" substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH) ".txt") }' targets.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example I would prefer the patterns inside the script.
I will use two lines changing the patterns to simple strings and finish with a `sed` command.

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # Remove qouble quotes (if any present)
    line=${line//\"}
    # Remove \s (sed command will add \s,)
    line=${line//\\s}
    # line is now like 1.2 or 2.1

    sed -n "/\s${line}/w target_${line}.txt" targets.txt
done < patterns.txt
```